# Ajax.ActionLink does not call controller action and its view

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

Here, the actionlink 'Get Students' in `TeacherIndex` view of `TeacherController`  must call `StudentController` and action method `StudentList` and then go to the view `StudentIndex`.

**TeacherIndex.cshtml in TeacherController:**

```
@model IEnumerable<StudentMVC.Models.TeacherEntity>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TeacherId)
    </th>
    ...       
</tr>
@if (Model != null)
{

foreach (var item in Model)
{
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TeacherId)
    </td>
    ...
    <td>              
        @Ajax.ActionLink("Get Students", "StudentList", "Student", new { id = item.TeacherId }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" })         
    </td>
</tr>
}
}
```

**StudentController:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult StudentList(int TeacherId)
    {
        List<StudentEntity> studentList = new List<StudentEntity>();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Moviedb"].ConnectionString);            
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_Student", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TeacherId", TeacherId);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            StudentEntity student = new StudentEntity();
            student.StudentId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["StudentId"]);
            //...              
            studentList.Add(student);
        }
        con.Close();
        return View("StudentIndex", studentList);
    }
```

But here, instead of that, shows

> Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found.
>
> Requested URL: /Student/StudentList/1

Answer (score 3):

the name of parameter should be same. use this :

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Get Students", "StudentList", "Student", new { @TeacherId = item.TeacherId }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" })
```

Comment: I have tried with the above code. But there is no change on error.